# How do get an activity to reload when the user hits the back button in a child activity

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, back

I have an activity that launches the **Contact picker** in the `onCreate` method.  When the user selects a **contact**, that **user's ID** gets passed to a new `child activity`.  If the user presses the back key however, they get presented with a blank screen cause the `onCreate` doesn't seem to be getting called again.

I've tried, `onRestart` and `onResume`, which fix the back issue, but what happens it a race condition in which it will make the call to open up an `Contact picker` activity before the *ID* is passed to the `child activity`.

EDIT:
I'm using API 2.3.3.

I've tried the overloading the onBack method in the child activity to launch a new activity.  But doing changes how the rendering of the page changes is done.  When you launch a new activity the new activity comes in from the right hand side of the screen, but when you hit back the normal implementation causes the previous screen to slide in from the left-hand side.  If I overload the onBack to call a new activity, what happens is the user hits the back button and a screen comes in from the right hand side of the screen as opposed to the left.  I would need to have the window sliding be the same as the default pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call onCreate on back key pressed. However you can do one thing that finish your contact picker activity. Override the function onBackPressed in Child activity and start a new Activity there.

Comment: does this created orphaned activities if i don't go back to the original activity and don't close it?

Comment: it will dump stack in ActivityManager. It will be better to finish off the activity so that it doesnt consume user's battery

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            moveTaskToBack(false);//this will not allow to go back

            //Here put your code i.e start new activity but first finish current activity

            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: isn't this the same thing as just calling the onBackPressed method?  Though i geuss i didn't mention what api i was using.  Also what about the orignal calling parent activity?